# Is there a formal name for this type of knot?

Tags: knot-theory

My (undergrad) research group and I were working with this one specific class of knots, and we don't know quite how to search up their qualities to find out if they have a name.

Basically, they are knots with only one twist in their center, with some odd number x of crossings in their center twist. The trefoil is one such knot, with x=3. The next colorable one is at x=9. I don't think we're talking about Twist Knots, of which the Trefoil is also one such knot, because to my untrained eye the two look different. See below for x=9 "8-Bigon Twisty Knot" as we preliminarily called it:

[knot with one twist and 9 crossings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEBmV.jpg)

So, do you know if these kinds of knots have a name? Or should we just call them "knot with one twist and x crossings"...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretzel_link

Comment: Ok, I was thinking of calling them (0,x,0) pretzel knots, but is that a thing? I thought for it to be classified as a pretzel knot the number of crossings in a tangle has to be more than 0

Comment: The pictured knot is the [$(2,9)$ torus knot](http://katlas.org/wiki/T(9,2)). If there is one twist and $k$ crossings, then it is the $(2,k)$ torus knot (or link). With more than one twist region, perhaps it would be a pretzel knot or link, depending on how the twist regions are arranged.

Comment: Thank you Adam, that makes sense. I can see how I can redraw these as torus knots.

Answer (score 3):

This is the (9,2) torus knot, which you can draw this way:

[image: (9,2) torus knot]

Comment: Thanks! This will help us in our midterm report and undergrad conference.